# How do I fake System.Web.HttpClientCertificate?

Tags: c#, mocking, client, certificate

I want to write unit tests for a WCF web service. The service uses HttpContext.Current. I already managed to Fake it by adding a Fake Assembly to System.Web and some code like:

```
[Test]
public void TestMyService()
{
  using (ShimsContext.Create())
  {
    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", "");
    HttpContext httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
    System.Web.Fakes.ShimHttpContext.CurrentGet = () => { return httpContext; };
    System.Web.Fakes.ShimHttpClientCertificate.AllInstances.IsPresentGet = (o) => { return true; };
  }
}
```

But my service also needs the ClientCertificate:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate.IsPresent) // <== Exception in unit test!
  throw new Exception("ClientCertificate is missing");
_clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);
```

Now in the marked line the unit test throws a NullReferenceException:

> Result Message:   System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object. Result StackTrace:    at
>   System.Web.HttpClientCertificate..ctor(HttpContext context) at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.CreateHttpClientCertificateWithAssert() at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_ClientCertificate() at (my method) at
>   TestMyService()

How can I set up the ClientCertificate for the unit tests? I don´t know how the create an HttpClientCertificate object to pass by a Shim, because there is not appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
Because the Exception came from the constructor of HttpClientCertificate I also had to fake it. I simple do nothing in the faked constructor:

```
System.Web.Fakes.ShimHttpClientCertificate.ConstructorHttpContext = (o, httpCont) => { };
```

Additionally in order to get a useful client certificate with *HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate* in my unit test I fake:

```
byte[] clientCertBytes = {0x30, 0x82, 0x03, ...., 0xd3};
System.Web.Fakes.ShimHttpClientCertificate.AllInstances.CertificateGet = (o) =>
  {
    return clientCertBytes;
  };
```

The clientCertBytes are the RawData of an X509Certificate2 object which I created in a debug session where I created this object from a file (could also be done from certificate store).